# MvvmCross Xamarin-Forms Viewmodel return values and back navigation

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvmcross

It's the standard Mvvm problem of getting results back from a view-model.

MvvmCross v5's navigation service has brought in some nice looking solutions to this, but I'm having trouble with it in practice. Using it with Xamarin-forms and testing android.

The setup is a main view with a button with a command bound that calls a second view that gets a value back from a list.

https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/fundamentals/navigation

This page suggests a new system using this to call the new view and specify a return type/value:

```
var result = await _navigationService.Navigate<NewViewModelType, Paramtype, ResultType>(param);
```

Which works nicely, then in the NewViewModelType to return it (currently) says:

```
await _navigationService.Close(this, new ResultType()); // this overload isn't there in 5.1
```

That overload doesn't exist, but you can use the Close method of the MvxViewModel base (if anyone's hit this issue):

```
 await Close(new ResultType());
```

Testing in the android emulator it works nicely when you close using this command.
But if you navigate away from the new view model with the back button the original button is greyed out and we never receive a return value in the main view.
I'd like to be able to press back to cancel out, but the button being disabled / that await left hanging is a problem.

So how should I handle this.  Is there a nice way to return a default on navigation?  Or is there a clean way to intercept the back command and return a default/null?

--

Here are my actual bindings and the relevant functions in case I've done something obviously dumb.  Operator here is an individual, not a programming operator.
View binding

```
<Button Text="{res:Translate Operator}" Command="{Binding SelectOperatorCommand}" />
```

View Model button Command

```
public IMvxCommand SelectOperatorCommand =>
    new MvxAsyncCommand(async () =>
    {
        var result = await _navigationService.Navigate<OperatorSelectViewModel, Operator, Operator>(_Operator);
        Operator = result; // we never get here if you press back in the next view
    });
```

The second View model (select from a list) init and close command

```
    public override Task Initialize(Operator parameter)
    {
        _selectedOperator = parameter;
        return base.Initialize();
    }

    public IMvxAsyncCommand CloseCommand =>
        new MvxAsyncCommand(async () =>
        {
            await Close(_selectedOperator); 
            // everything is happy is we exit this way.
        });
```

Comment: I think this is a bug in the MvvmCross Forms presenter. Can you make an issue on Github with a reproduction so we can fix it?

Comment: Thanks @Martijn00, I've tried to bring it up to 5.2 but it looks like it's all changed. Honestly I'm struggling to get a solution using Visual Studio that will build.  None of the templates or the forms starter pack produce anything the works out of the box now.